# Roll two dice - probability distribution function of one even and one odd

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expectation, dice

**Question**

Roll two six-sided fair dice.

(a) What is the probability that you roll exactly one even and one odd value?

(b) Suppose we roll the dice $n$ times. Let $X=$ the total number of rolls with one odd and one even value. What is the probability distribution function of $X$?

(c) Suppose you win one dollar when you roll one even and one odd value. You also lose one dollar when you roll two odds or two evens. Let $Y=$ the total gain for $n$ rolls. What is $E[Y]$?

I am a little stuck on parts (b) and (c), but hopefully my work isn't *too* far off!

**My Attempt**

(a) P(first odd and second even) + P(first even and second odd) = $\frac{3}{6}*\frac{3}{6} + \frac{3}{6}*\frac{3}{6} = \frac{1}{2}$

(b) I'm not positive on the random variable $X$. I have assumed it as $X=0$ where there are no evens. $X=1$ when there is one odd and one even, $X=2$ when there are two evens.

The probability distribution is as follows: $P(X=0)=\frac{1}{4}$, $P(X=1)=\frac{1}{2}$, $P(X=2)=\frac{1}{4}$.

(c) $E[Y] = \frac{1}{4}*(-1) + \frac{1}{2}*(1) + \frac{1}{4}*(-1)=0$. So the total gain for $n$ rolls is zero dollars.

Answer (score 0):

(a) Okay.

(b) You roll the *pair* of dice $n$ times.   That is two dice on each trial.   A success on a trial is an odd and an even, occurring with the probability you calculated for $(a)$.

So, for some number $n$, you have $n$ Bernoulli trials with success rate $1/2$.   $X$ is the count of successes in these $n$ trials.

(c) As above.   Express $Y$ in terms of $X$.   Find $\mathsf E(X)$.   Then find $\mathsf E(Y)$ from that.

*Tip:* $Y$ is ...

> the count of successes minus the count of failures.